# Recursively find and replace contents of one file using a key from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, replace

I need to use one file as an input to find and replace in another file. The following command does so, but only for the first column for each line. I need this to happen for every column.

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{$1=a[$1];print}' OFS=',' file1 file2 > fileout
```

The two files look like this

file1 (the key):

```
0,name0
1,name1
2,name2
3,name3
4,name4
```

file2:

```
23,45,0
41,1,2,4
4,5,22,100
10,20,31,51,1
33,3
16,111,3
```

The output should be:

```
23,45,name0
41,name1,name2,name4
name4,5,22,100
10,20,31,51,name1
33,name3
16,111,name3
```

Comment: Why not apply one column at a time?

Comment: had a typo in my previous loop. got it to work awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i];print}' OFS=','

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i];print}' OFS=',' file1 file2 > fileout
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think above will work. Result on my system:

```
,,name0
,name1,name2,name4
name4,,,
,,,,name1
,name3
,,name3
```

Try instead

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[$i]) $i=a[$i]} 1' OFS=',' file1 file2
23,45,name0
41,name1,name2,name4
name4,5,22,100
10,20,31,51,name1
33,name3
16,111,name3
```

Answer (score 1):

It could also be done with `sed`:

```
sed -f <(sed 's|,|$/,|;s|^|s/,|;s|$|/|' f1) f2
```

As pointed out by Kusalananda, this solution uses process substitution, which not all common shells support. However, there are other ways to achieve the same effect.

How does this work? The basic idea is to transform file `f1` into a `sed` program that will in turn transform file `f2`. The `sed` command in parentheses transforms each line of file `f1` into an `s///` command.

Comment: Since the given command is fairly complex, it would be good to have an explanation of how it operates. Also, it seems to require `bash` (for the process substitution), and I'm not quite sure why you escape that `$` in the first substitution's replacement part (but maybe you could explain that too?).

Comment: The escape was unnecessary. Thanks for pointing that out. I think the program is a little clearer now.